# How to retrieve information in the first section of the raw data only by regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

Below is a sample of the raw data which my code will process by regular expressions:

```
raw_data = '''
name        :   John
age         :   26
gender      :   male
occupation  :   teacher

Father
---------------------
name        :   Bill
age         :   52
gender      :   male

Mother
---------------------
name        :   Mary
age         :   48
gender      :   female
'''
```

I want to retrieve the following part of information from the raw data and store it in a dictionary:

```
dict(name = 'John', age = 26, gender = 'male', occupation = 'teacher')
```

However, when I run my code as follows, it does not work as I expect:

```
import re
p = re.compile('[^-]*?^([^:\-]+?):([^\r\n]*?)$', re.M)
rets = p.findall(raw_data)

infoAboutJohnAsDict = {}

if rets != []:
  for ret in rets:
    infoAboutJohnAsDict[ret[0]] = ret[1]
else:
  print("Not match.")

print(f'rets = {rets}')
print(f'infoAboutJohnAsDict = {infoAboutJohnAsDict}')
```

Can anyone give me any suggestion about how I should modify my code to achieve what I intend to do?

Comment: Do you need to process _all_ three entries, or just the very first one?

Comment: Just the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using regular expressions.  We can first trim off the latter portion of the input which you don't want using `re.sub`.  Then, use `re.findall` to find all key value pairs for John, and convert to a dictionary.

```py
raw_data = re.sub(r'\s+\w+\s+-+.*', '', raw_data, flags=re.S)
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)', raw_data)
d = dict()
for m in matches:
    d[m[0]] = m[1]

print(d)
# {'gender': 'male', 'age': '26', 'name': 'John', 'occupation': 'teacher'}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to achieve the same effect without using ' re.sub '? In my original code, I creates a function which is responsible for processing the raw data and returns the matched part in the form of the dictionary. This function will take the ' raw_data ' and a regular expression as its arguments. And I hope to keep it like that. (Sorry I didn't make this part clear in my original question.) If you or anyone know how to do this, please share it with me. I will appreciate your support.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why your function can call `re.findall` but cannot also call `re.sub`.  You _could_ just call `re.findall` on the original input and then just retain the first 4 matches, e.g. use `re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)', raw_data)[0:4]` with the rest of my answer as above.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I think your suggestion of ' re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)', raw_data)[0:4] ' might work for me. I will modify my function to make it return the matched data. And then I will store the first 4 items in the returned data in a dictionary. I avoid using ' re.sub ' because I think it is a solution specific for this case. The function which processes the raw data with the regular expressions in my original code also needs to process other kinds of data with different regular expression patterns.